# Count groups of characters at the start of each line

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I really want to find the number of space groups (tabs in my case) before a line, and I have a piece of code that seems to work, but it's *really* bad and slow. Please view it below:

```js
var data = "test\n    another test\none more"
var tabs = []
data.split("\n").forEach((line, index) => {
  tabs[index] = Math.floor((line.length - line.replace(/^(.*?)[^\ ]/g, "").length) / 4)
})
alert(tabs.join(", "))
```

Also, only need a way to find groups of four spaces, if that's possible. Is there a way to do that the fastest?

Comment: Not sure it is the fastest, but a regular expression and one loop to get the length `"test\n    another test\none more".match(/(^|\n)\s*/g).map(x=>x.replace(/\n/,'').length/4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
data.split('\n').map(x => (x.match(/ {4}/gy) || []).length);
```

See an updated demo:

```js
var data = "test\n    another test\n        one more";
var tabs = data.split('\n').map(x => (x.match(/ {4}/gy) || []).length);
console.log(tabs.join(","))
```

Here,

- `.split('\n')` - splits the string into lines
- `.map(x => (x.match(/ {4}/gy) || []).length)` - gets each line and applies the `.match(/ {4}/gy)` on  it. `/ {4}/gy` matches all, multiple occurrences (due to `g` flag) of four spaces from the start of string, and the next match only occurs exactly after the previous match (thanks to the sticky `y` flag).
- The `(... || []).length` gets either the count of matched groups of four spaces or `0` if there was no match (`|| []` ensures we get zeros without exceptions).

Comment: straightforward and nicely explained.

Comment: I don't think I was explaining it properly: I'm only trying to find the number of groups of four spaces before lines.

Comment: Don't we need a "^" at the regex start to make sure we're not looking later into the string, like `test    test`?

Comment: @InfiniteGamer Now, it is `y` flag that ensures it.